# Find connected features by type in utility network?

Tags: trace, utility-network, connectivity-analysis

I have a storm drain geodatabase with digitized direction flow.  I am trying to find catch basins (upstream) that drain to other catchbasins (downstream) as opposed to a junction structure or an outlet.  The purpose is to be able to add trash collection devices on downstream catch basins instead of every catch basin.  So I need to find where these CBs are connected to each other.  Is their a programmatic way to do this?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_tracing_on_geometric_networks/002r0000002s000000/

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris.  Unfortunately it seems I have to create a flag on every line and run analysis.  I'm trying to find a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was using the **Feature Vertices to Points** tool with the option **Both Ends** on the storm drain lines.  Next I found the XY for each point, concatenated them and summarized on that field.  If I had 2 or more points that intersected a catch basin it meant something was coming in and coming out.  It narrowed my search down by 80%.!

Flow that consolidates in a downstream catch basin.  One point created on the north catch basin, 2 were created on the south.  One from the incoming line and one from the outgoing. 
[image]

Table summarized to find 2 or more.  These have consolidated flow.
[image]

Comment: This sounds interesting - could you click 'edit' and add some graphics (screen shots?) with examples of how exactly you used the tools, and the outputs?